# python dxfgrabber module for extracting the specific value and print

Tags: python, data-extraction

I currently work on python codes but I have no idea on how to extract all the value I need and print them out.
For example:

```
 100 AcDbEntity 8 1 100 AcDbText 10 107.3 20 828.23 30 0.0 40 5.0 1 pr:HC336635004.F
```

I wish to get all the values or strings under '1', code'1' here means xrefpath name

one line of my codes would be like this:

> references = [entity for entity in dxf.entities if entity.dxftype == 'AcDbText' and block.xrefpath == '1']

here is the documentation I am referring to, I really had a hard time one this as a python beginner
https://dxfgrabber.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#query-blocks